# How to create a hierarchical nested object based on parent-id

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, data-structures

I have a flat array of object which maintains the parent id.
I need to convert it into a nested JSON object so that we can display it in a tree structure in the frontend

```
 {
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"India",
         "id":1563389084200625
      },
      {
         "parentId":1563389084200625,
         "name":"Karnataka",
         "id":2492715807428324
      },
      {
         "name":"Bangalore",
         "parentId":2492715807428324,
         "id":3889975945703906
      }
   ]
}
```

need to convert to

```
{
   "items":{
      "name":"India",
      "id":1563389084200625,
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"Karnataka",
            "id":2492715807428324,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"Bangalore",
                  "id":3889975945703906
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a higher order function `buildTree()` that takes `parentId` as a parameter and returns function that takes `item` as a parameter. The inner function creates a new object using spread `...` operator. It also filters the the items belonging to the parent by their `parentId`. If there are any items found, it uses map() method and recursion to build a tree of these items.
The final output `nestedData` is created by filtering top-level items that  and mapping them to `buildTree()`.The `undefined` is passed as the `parentId` param in that case.

```js
const data = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "India",
      id: 1563389084200625,
    },
    {
      parentId: 1563389084200625,
      name: "Karnataka",
      id: 2492715807428324,
    },
    {
      name: "Bangalore",
      parentId: 2492715807428324,
      id: 3889975945703906,
    },
  ],
};

const buildTree = (parentId) => (item) => {
  const children = data.items.filter((child) => child.parentId === item.id);
  return {
    ...item,
    ...(children.length > 0 && { children: children.map(buildTree(item.id)) }),
  };
};

const nestedData = {
  items: data.items.filter((item) => !item.parentId).map(buildTree(undefined)),
};

console.log(nestedData);
```

Comment: How do I modify the code so that the `data` is received as a parameter instead of defined above?